# Making list to a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list like this

```
list = [('a', 3418), ('b', 3544), ('c', 1153), ('d', 2155), ('e', 2254), ('f', 2654), ('g', 2982), ('h', 3267), ('i', 3056), ('j', 820), ('k', 2987)]
```

and i need to get dictionary like this:

```
dictionary = {'a' : 3418, 'b' : 3544, 'c' : 1153}
```

tried using

```
dict = {k:v for k,v in (x.split(',') for x in list) }
```

but get error

> AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'split'

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way:

```
In [1]: x =  [('a', 3418), ('b', 3544), ('c', 1153), ('d', 2155), ('e', 2254), ('f', 2654), ('g', 2982), ('h', 3267), ('i', 3056), ('j', 820), ('k', 2987)]

In [2]: dict(x)
Out[2]: 
{'a': 3418,
 'b': 3544,
 'c': 1153,
 'd': 2155,
 'e': 2254,
 'f': 2654,
 'g': 2982,
 'h': 3267,
 'i': 3056,
 'j': 820,
 'k': 2987}
```

From the `dict` docstring:

```
class dict(object)
 |  dict() -> new empty dictionary
 |  dict(mapping) -> new dictionary initialized from a mapping object's
 |      (key, value) pairs
 |  dict(iterable) -> new dictionary initialized as if via:
 |      d = {}
 |      for k, v in iterable:
 |          d[k] = v
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way, IMHO, would be to use a dictionary comprehension:

```
>>> l = [('a', 3418), ('b', 3544), ('c', 1153), ('d', 2155), ('e', 2254), ('f', 2654), ('g', 2982), ('h', 3267), ('i', 3056), ('j', 820), ('k', 2987)]
>>> d = {x[0] : x[1] for x in l}
>>> d
{'a': 3418, 'c': 1153, 'b': 3544, 'e': 2254, 'd': 2155, 'g': 2982, 'f': 2654, 'i': 3056, 'h': 3267, 'k': 2987, 'j': 820}
```